# What model/collection to be used for Custom Product Attribute

Tags: reports, custom-attributes

I have a custom product attribute "Manufacturer". I need to include it in Magento default reports at the admin panel Reports->Products->Low Stock. Can anyone say from which collection I need to fetch the value. It is not present in 'catalog/product'. Im able to get only the corresponding Manufacturer's id. Not the value of the id.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value from an Id like this:

```
$option = Mage::getModel('eav/attribute_option')->load($id);
```

See what `$option->getData()` looks like and get what you need from there.